# Can I print each map value with a for loop with this code?

Tags: c++

I hope you can help me out with my idea or something better (C++). Im trying to print out the second values of a map into a for loop which will already print out the first values of another map. Is it possible to do it with find like im trying here: (thanks in advance)

map1:

```
map<double, int> map1 = {
            {51.5, 29},
            {25.2, 87},
            {13.4, 91},
            {89.2, 100},
            {7.4, 85} };

map<string, int> map2;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cout << "Ingrese cadena " << cont++ << ": " << endl;
    cin >> cadena;
    map2[cadena];
}
cout << endl;

cout << "Desplegar map2" << endl;
for(map<string, int>::iterator mapear = map2.begin(); mapear != map2.end(); ++mapear){
    cout << mapear->first << " " << map1.find(51.5)->second << endl;
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: This code is incomplete and should not compile as  a typo `cont++`.

Comment: It does compile, I have cont initiated to 0 on the top, sorry I did not include that declaration. What I need is a way to print out all second values from map1 into new map. The way I have it right now will only print 29 on all map2. Thanks anyway @rustyhu

Comment: You should make your purpose clear in the question description, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first.

Comment: @rustyhu sorry if its not clear enough, the question I posted asks " Im trying to print out the second values of a map..." As my code is right now, will only print 1 value, I need all second values

Comment: Do you concern about the order? Why not use a `vector` or array like `[29, 87, 91, 100, 85]` to store all the second values you want to print out, because in the code when "Desplegar map2" these values are relevant to `map2` keys, not `map1`.

Comment: @rustyhu yes, I thought of that, and definitely would be the easiest way. But this is an assignment I have, so I have to find a way to pull those values out, but my head is about to explode trying to find a way haha!

Answer (score 0):

This will print out in a certain order by the key order of the 2 maps, respectively.

```cpp
cout << "Desplegar map2" << endl;
auto iter1 = map1.begin();
auto iter2 = map2.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << iter2->first << " " << iter1->second << endl;
    iter1++;
    iter2++;
}

cout << endl;
```

Comment: Is there a way to have map1[] retrieve all the second values? The code how I have it and how you posted it here will only print out one value, which is 29 for 51.5.